# RoboFrameWork:: WebDriverException: Message: Unexpected error launching Internet Explorer

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, robotframework, selenium2library, selenium-iedriver

I am trying to run my script in ie i am getting below error. But same works fine with firefox, chrome.

- Selenium :: 3.7.1
- IE Version :: 11 (32 bit)
- IEDriverServer :: tried with 3.6 and 3.7 (all 32 bit)
- Robotframework :: 3.0.2
- OS  :: windows 7 Enterprise edition (64 bit)

The error message is:

```
WebDriverException: Message: Unexpected error launching Internet Explorer. 
IELaunchURL() returned HRESULT 80070012 ('There are no more files.') 
for URL 'http://localhost:64094/'
```

below settings are applicable for IE.

- Internet security options for all the zones, the checkbox is unchecked for Enable protected mode.
- zoom level is set to 100%

Comment: On which OS are you running the webdriver. Are you running 64 bit or 43 bit webdriver. Are you running IE 11 32 bit or 64 bit?

Comment: i am using windows 7 Enterprise edition which is of 64 bit.  IE is 32 bit and webdriver also 32 bit

Comment: Did you implement the [Registry Setting](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver#required-configuration) as well? Additionally, how are you running your tests? Locally or via a terminal? If the latter, have a look at this [Selenium User Group](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/selenium-users/EXrE5uATK1o/_6Yp40kpAgAJ)  post where the suggestion was to run `psexec \\localhost -i 0`

Comment: thx for your time. Registry Settings are kept correctly before we start our scripts. I am using Pycharm to execute script .e.g: pybot -d result scripts/test.robot ... Now i added psexec to my windows/system32. but when i am running this command psexec \\localhost:5555 -i 0 test.robot (OR)psexec \\localhost:5555 -i 0 pybot test.robot.. I am getting this error..Couldn't access localhost:5555:
The network path was not found.

Make sure that the default admin$ share is enabled on localhost:5555.
NOT sure if this is the right way

Comment: Hi @A.Kootstra, any other way to avoid this issue..? pl help

Comment: I'm out of options as well. The issue seems to have occurred over the past couple of years, but other than the suggestions I've given I've not seen any concrete resolutions.